# Is it really necessary to flood a question with SQL injection warnings?

Tags: discussion

Almost every question I read concerning SQL these days is flooded with comments about **SQL injection**; Deprecated PHP `mysql_*` functions etc, which don't relate to the question being asked. I'm not against imparting knowledge, but it does get a little silly when some really helpful comments are being lost in amongst the frothing bile of angry programmers.

Is it our place to warn about possible future issues, that may or may not happen? Or just answer the question and let the OP figure it out if/when that something does occur?

Comment: By "flood" do you mean multiple people all leaving their own comments under the same post warning about the same thing? I guess there are certain things in life that bear repeating...

Comment: I used "flood" for lack of a better term, but you can almost guarantee that they'll be plenty of comments pretty much all saying exactly the same thing. In light of @Servy's answer, I can understand 1 or 2, but it seems like other users just tend to jump on the band wagon, for the sake of it.

Comment: SQL injection isn't the only thing that people pile on comments about. Pay the review queues a visit and you'll find a couple of cases of people piling on review comments in the same way, for whatever reason. It's like people have forgotten that comments can be upvoted.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, some of that is people posting comments at the same time, and not seeing other people's comments.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, but I haven't actually seen that in a while. All the recent cases I've seen have comments between 1 and 4 *hours* instead of seconds or minutes apart. No real excuse for that.

Comment: I'd much rather deal with some annoying duplicate comments pointing out a vulnerability in my code than just "figure it out if/when that something does occur."

Comment: Even sillier when the question is ABOUT SQL injection, the answers contradict each other, and opposite answers both get huge upvote scores.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely is necessary.

The negative consequences for leaving in a SQL injection vulnerability are extremely significant (and will often be more concerning than whatever problem the question is asking about), and resolving the problem generally is going to involve a significant enough re-write of the problem that there's a noticeable chance that the underlying problem will cease to be relevant.  Even if that doesn't happen, the earlier the OP (and other readers) learn of the problem, the easier it'll be to refactor the code to use a safer querying tool.

Of course, the question can still be answered, if it's a good question.  A comment (or notation at the end of an answer) doesn't prohibit that from happening.

Of course, readers aren't *obligated* to bring up every issue they see that's tangentially related to the question.  If they don't want to take the time, they certainly don't *have* to, but they shouldn't be *prohibited* from pointing out those problems in an appropriate manner.

Comment: The most important and more frequent vulnerability is by far XSS. Why don't we agree to comment-flood questions with potential XSS opening, or when an XSRF leak is possible? Maybe because sql injection is the shortest mule, where everyone finds it easy to say his thing?

Comment: @IgorGreg If you notice an XSS problem with the code from a question I would *absolutely* encourage you to point it out.  Part of why I suspect it's not actually pointed out as often is that it's much harder to tell whether a given snippet has an XSS vulnerability with the small sections actually posted to SO questions, and people would want to be confident that the vulnerability actually exists before posting a comment pointing it out.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is absolutely necessary. SQL Injection is a big hazard and you can see much code around where you feel that people have no idea about correct parameter passing.

People should learn to write solid and stable solutions.

Comment: It is quite ironic that, on a question about the same comments piling up, you have decide to pile up the same *answer* four months later.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi because it is necessary! ;)