# Answering a question with other problems

Tags: discussion, answers

This question is similar to [this one regarding SQL injection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285163/is-it-really-necessary-to-flood-a-question-with-sql-injection-warnings).

Assuming somebody posts a question ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301617/what-is-wrong-with-my-query-or-syntax-here)) saying "What's wrong with my query?" and the answer is syntax related, or something of the like, what's the best approach to answering?

1. Answer the question, pointing out the syntax error which would make the code work
2. Answer the question, as above, and also point out that the code is vulnerable to SQL injection
3. Spam the comments on answers for people who have taken option #1 above rather than #2 or worse yet, just the SQL injection comment with no answer

The actual problem with this situation comes from somebody answering saying "Hey man, you're missing some quotes in your SQL statement - here's how it *should* look", then quickly having people telling you that *your* code is vulnerable to a myriad of security issues.

Would it be bad practice to answer someone's question and *only* give them the answer they're after, without pointing out other issues with the code? Is this what differentiates a good Stackoverflow user from a *great* one, or simply one that has enough time to do it every time they answer?

Comment: Personally, I tend to put the extra information if needed in the hope that they may actually listen and maybe learn something new. No harm can come from giving more information. I also tend to up-vote answers which have tried to go that extra bit for the questioner. Basically, I wouldn't say it's bad practice but the answer would be better with the other information. It depends on the answerer as an individual too.